# phpmyadmin process id very high and rapidly growing, is it normal?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I started working on a website recently and on phpmyadmin I see an unusually high (I think) data trafic (~1To/day) which isn't normal as the website is still very small and I'm the only user so far.

I've looked at pretty much everything on phpmyadmin settings and find nothing of relevance.

I've linked a picture of what I see (sorry my interface is in french):

https://ibb.co/LdLNsyq

The ids are rapidly growing (~ +25/s) even though every window is closed and I made sure there is no webpage opened nor users connected.

pressing kill gives me "phpMyAdmin couldn't kill the process 4247894. It was already closed"

So something is creating process very fast? 
I'm a little lost and I would need your help please

Comment: Don't link to external resources, try and keep your question self-contained.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you open/close connections frequently those ID values will go up rapidly. If you use a connection pool you can keep your connections open between requests. In general those ID values don't matter, they're just numbers.

The reason you can't kill them is because they are very short lived, that in some code you might have this:

```
$db = connect();
// One statement
$db->close();
```

Unless by chance you catch the connection in the middle of running the query it's going to get closed out before you can.

Note that creating a *large* number of connections can be a performance bottleneck, so look at connection pooling as a fix. Most (good) PHP database drivers support that in some form, e.g. PDO.

Comment: Does that stay true with the fact that I have no open pages?

Comment: There must be something opening pages or you wouldn't get connections. I'd check your server's "access log" to see what activity you have. I'd also look to see that there's no background processes running, like out of control PHP scripts stuck in a loop.